# How would I stop soundboard from playing a sound and instead play another sound?

Tags: python, playsound, python-playsound

I have taken code from online which listens for the user's keystrokes, in this case the two keys that will activate the code is "e" and ".". Both are linked to a dictionary which defines each with an mp3 file (consider it a shortcut). And then plays the mp3 file using playsound.

My problem is that when a sound is played, it does not allow me to press any other keys, I would like it that it acts as a usual soundboard in which I can repeatidly press the same button and the audio would play from the beginning again.

```
from time import sleep
import keyboard as kb
import playsound as ps

keymap_count = None
is_playing = False

def do_for_key(pressed_key, keymap):
    global keymap_count
    global is_playing
    if keymap_count is None:
        keymap_count = dict(zip(keymap, [0]*len(keymap)))

    for key in keymap:
        if kb.is_pressed(key) and is_playing == False:
            print(f"\n{key}: {keymap[key]}")
            ps.playsound(keymap[pressed_key])
            is_playing = True
        elif kb.is_pressed(key) and is_playing == True:
            is_playing = False
            ps.terminate()

def soundboard(keymap):
    for key in keymap:
        kb.on_press_key(key, lambda key_event: do_for_key(key_event.name, keymap))
    while True:
        try:
            sleep(0.05)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    example_keymap = {
        'e': "sound.mp3",
        '.': "smooth.mp3"
    }
    soundboard(example_keymap)
```

Here is my code.